# Adiabatic Invariant for nonoscillatory system

Tags: adiabatic, invariants

For oscillatory system (e.g. quantum harmonic oscillation with slowly changing effective spring constant), it is common to define the adiabatic invariant to be
$$I=\frac{H(t)}{\omega(t)}$$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of oscillation.

What about systems in which there isn't a well-defined oscillatory motion (e.g. [2-state system avoided crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem#Avoided_curve_crossing))? What is the corresponding adiabatic invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the classical adiabatic theorem with the quantum adiabatic theorem. In the quantum case, the adiabatic theorem says that you stay in an energy eigenstate as the parameters of the Hamiltonian are slowly varied. That makes perfect sense for both the two-state system and the harmonic oscillator.

In the particular case where the quantum system represents oscillatory motion in a potential well, you can then take the classical limit and apply the quantum adiabatic theorem, which tells you that
$$I = \oint p \, dq$$
is a classical adiabatic invariant. (Also, I have no idea where you got the idea that $I = H(t) / \omega(t)$, that isn't true even classically.)

Comment: The definition I provided is sourced from MIT 806 notes Eq. 1.6. So what is the range of validity of the definition? https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch6.pdf

Comment: @LeoL. That's _only_ for the harmonic oscillator. The more general definition of the (classical) adiabatic invariant is what I gave.

Comment: I see. Just making sure, is it valid only for *quantum* harmonic oscillator?

Comment: @LeoL. The entire discussion in that section is in the context of _classical_ mechanics. What would $I = H / \omega$ even mean in quantum mechanics? $I$ is supposed to be a number, while $H$ is an operator.

Comment: But there is a correspondence between the two in the sense that if we demote $H=\hbar\omega(N+1/2)$ from an operator to just a number, i.e. demoting the number operator to just a number (quantum number), then we have the WKB quantization condition $\oint pdq = 2\pi\hbar (n+1/2)$